# Get the URL path in Express.JS (without assets)

Tags: node.js, express

here I let you a question that is bothering me a little bit.

I have a middleware in my Express application that logs in a .txt file every path that I request. My code looks like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
   fs.writeFileSync('log.txt', req.originalUrl + '\n');
   next();
}
```

It works fine, but logs every resource from the request (the path of images, the path of css files, the path of js files) and I only want, the path present in the browser address bar.

Anyone knows how can I get that?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say: Hello, how is it going? :P

Answer (score 0):

you need to chose wisely the position of your middleware.

to achieve what you say you need to put your own midleware after assets middleware
exemple

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   fs.writeFileSync('log.txt', req.originalUrl + '\n');
   next();
})

app.get('/', () =>{
...
})
```

by doing this, your middleware will only be called if the path is not an asset.

Comment: Ohhhhhh you are a genius man! How could I not see that? Thanks!